# What are the correct Degrees of each Astronomical Constellation?

Tags: scripture

Each astronomical constellation is different is Size!

Some charts depict this fact:

[image]

Surely, by now we have an accurate measurement of these specific Degrees between astronomical constellations, I ask what they are, I need a precise answer, no guesses please.